# Colorize different chunks of text in same output with different colors

Tags: bash, colors

I have a script that spews out i/o data with `>>>` and `<<<` symbolising direction - either input (`<<<`) or output (`>>>`).

```
<timestamp> >>>>>>>>>>
loads
of
output

<timestamp> <<<<<<<<<<
loads
of
input
```

I'd like to take this output and colorize the input with one color and the output with another - sort of like how `git diff` colors the differences in file versions.

How can I do this with the least amount of typing and preferably as a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this with `awk` works for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ce="\033[0m"}
     />>>/{cs="\033[1;31m"}
     /<<</{cs="\033[1;32m"}
     {print cs$0ce}' your.data
```

That is:

```
BEGIN {
    ce = "\033[0m"
}
/>>>/ {
    cs = "\033[1;31m"
}
/<<</ {
    cs = "\033[1;32m"
}
{
    print cs $0 ce
}
```

Comment: Or `awk '/>>>/{s=1}/<<</{s=2}$0="\33[1;3"s"m"$0"\33[m"'` to reduce the typing further.

Comment: Wow - that was quick.  Can't even begin to decipher exactly how that works, but it's exactly what I was after.  If possible and you've got time to spare, please educate me.

Comment: @AnthonyK, that's actually quite straightforward awk. The basic syntax is `/pattern/ { action }`, the action is executed on lines matching the pattern. Then it's just setting variables with the [escape codes for the colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), and printing out those and the line itself (`$0`).

Comment: @ilkkachu: got it. I was thinking that the variable `s` gets reset on each run.  But I now understand that once set, it holds until the logic requires it to change.  Is it possible to toggle the variable on each occurrence of a certain keyword instead of looking for different markers (that ones now easy)?

Comment: Answered my own question - `awk 'BEGIN {s-0};/keyword/{s+=1}{c=s%2+1}$0="\033[1;3"c"m"$0"\033[0m"'`

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of all-shell, terminal-independent, semantic solutions, here is another way to do colors that utilizes `tput`, which uses the terminfo database to provide the correct color changing sequence for whatever terminals it recognizes:

```
black=$(tput setaf 0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
off=$(tput sgr0)

echo ${red}some red text${blue} some blue text${green} and green${off} and back to normal.
```